# Mapping multiple rows to 2 entities using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, oracle11g

I have an entity "Project" with multiple "subTask" entities (List). Now normaly this would be simple and seperated in the DB and easy to map. But in this case I've only got 1 view. This means a row for every subTask with project data on every record.

Example:

```
projectId | projectName | subTaskId | subTaskName | ....
---------------------------------------------------------
1         | projectTest | 1         | subTaskTest | ....
1         | projectTest | 2         | subTaskTest2| ....
```

I'm trying to find a way to map this using JPA but i'm unsure if this is at all possible and if so which would be the best way to do this.

Has anyone tried this before? Could you point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

Some extra info: I need to create a webservice which can return Projects (including all subTasks). And it's ofcourse read only, no writing or editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two Java classes`ProjectEmbedded` - [Embeddable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html) and `SubTask` - Entity. This is the correct solution, because you cannot insert new entries in this view (like new projects)

```
@Embeddable
public class ProjectEmbedded {
    private Long projectId;
    private String projectName;
}


@Entity
public class SubTask {
    private Long subTaskId;
    private String subTaskName;
    @Embedded
    private ProjectEmbedded project;
}
```

Comment: Well since I need a project object to send out a webservice. I'd need to create the projects and add the subtasks to it manualy then by looping over all the SubTask entities i get?

Comment: As long as you do not want/try to change the data (as it is a view), you can add new fields to the classes that are not mapped to the DB. Or alternatively you could define some [DTOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to change the structure of data used in your web service.

Comment: Well i only need to read so there is no problem there.

But what i'm wondering is this: If i need to create a project manualy and loop over all the subTasks to add them to the project. Then i'd basically be doing the same as normal JDBC calls (getting resultsets and looping over the data to create the objects). In which case it might be better to use normal JDBC instead of JPA. Since I wont be getting any added value by using JPA and JDBC might even have better performance in this case.

Comment: You won't get performance problems, don't worry about that. Use JPA if your project will get bigger, otherwise, if you feel more comfortable with JDBC, use that.